# How to jquery validation under select2 field - I tried everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a problem with select2 and Jquery and Checkboxes. I made a form with some different fields. The validate warning is showed above Select field when I added the validate of checkboxes.  When I did not add this code:

[checkboxes validate code][1]

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

the warning is shown under select2 field but the checkboxes warnings are showed wrong:
[Wrong warning on checkoboxes][3] 
 I do not why, can somebody look to the code and correct me?

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[form printscreen][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Can you generate the same case in the fiddle so that it can help resolve the issue?

Comment: Your HTML code only contains the `zgoda3` checkbox, which doesn't have any errorPlacement code. I also noticed that you have two `errorPlacements:` keys in your object, this means that the last `errorPlacements` function will replace the first one.

Comment: Please, improve your code section. There's too much indentation, so that it is difficult to read your code. Furthermore you should not post code as images but as plain text. People willing to help you may need to copy your code in their answers,but nobody will copy text from an image.

Comment: I would like to post the Code and demo but I receive an error when I rendering it. I do not know why. I am a new person here, maybe I do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" name="myForm" action="">
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <label for="terms">terms : </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms">
        <div id="errorToShow"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

Script:

```
       $("#myForm").validate({
            rules: {
                terms: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                terms: "select the checkbox"
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.attr("name") == "terms") {
                    error.appendTo("#errorToShow");
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
```

Place the  contains id="errorToShow" where you want to show error. This works for me.
The error message will be shown in

```
<div id="errorToShow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. So I do it a little different. The validation code is    now:

```
                $("#signupForm").validate({
                    debug: false,
                    errorClass: "has-error",
                    errorElement: "span",
                   rules: {

                        miejscowosc: {
                            required: true,
                            lettersonly: true,
                        },
                                               wojewodztwo: {
                            required: true,
                        },


                    errorContainer: $('#errorContainer'),
                    // enabling this will display error labels in the container error
                    // errorLabelContainer: $('#errorContainer ul'),
                    // wrapper: 'li',

                    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).addClass(errorClass); //.removeClass(errorClass);
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
                    },
                    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).removeClass(errorClass); //.addClass(validClass);
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
                    },
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                        } else if (element.hasClass('select2')) {
                            error.insertAfter(element.next('span'));
                        } 
                        else if (element.attr("name") == "zgoda") {
                            error.insertAfter("#checkboxError"); 
                            } 

                            else if (element.attr("name") == "zgoda1") {
                            error.insertAfter("#checkboxError1"); 
                            } 
                            else if (element.attr("name") == "zgoda2") {
                            error.insertAfter("#checkboxError2"); 
                            } 

                        else {
                            error.insertAfter(element);
                        }
                    },



                });
```

and now the warning message is Under select2 so It is Ok.

The code Of select2 is

```
var Formularz = function () {
                    return {
                        //main function to initiate the module
                        init: function () {
                            function format(state) {
                                if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
                                return state.id.toLowerCase() + state.text;
                            }

                            $("#Select_Wojewodztwo").select2({
                                placeholder: "Wybierz Wojewodztwo",
                                allowClear: true,
                                formatResult: format,
                                width: '100%',  
                                formatSelection: format,
                                escapeMarkup: function (m) {
                                    return m;
                                }
                            });                                     
                        }
                    };
                }();

                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    Formularz.init();
                });
```

the second my problem is has-error does not wotk in select2 field and doesnt highlight it on red.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwQoK.png)

the code in form is:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 form-group">                                            
                                        <div class="col-lg-12 form-label">
                                            Województwo
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="col-lg-12 ">
                                            <select name="wojewodztwo" id="Select_Wojewodztwo" class="select2 form-control selection">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="Dolnoslaskie">Dolnośląskie</option>
                                                <option value="Kujawsko-pomorskie">Kujawsko-pomorskie</option>
                                                <option value="Lubelskie">Lubelskie</option>
                                                <option value="Lubuskie">Lubuskie</option>
                                                <option value="Lodzkie">Łódzkie</option>
                                                <option value="Malopolskie">Małopolskie</option>
                                                <option value="Mazowieckie">Mazowieckie</option>
                                                <option value="Opolskie">Opolskie</option>
                                                <option value="Podkarpackie">Podkarpackie</option>
                                                <option value="Podlaskie">Podlaskie</option>
                                                <option value="Pomorskie">Pomorskie</option>
                                                <option value="Slaskie">Śląskie</option>
                                                <option value="Swietokrzyskie">Świętokrzyskie</option>
                                                <option value="Warminsko-mazurskie">Warmińsko-mazurskie</option>
                                                <option value="Wielkopolskie">Wielkopolskie</option>
                                                <option value="Zachodniopomorskie">Zachodniopomorskie</option>
                                            </select>                                                                       
                                        </div>      
                                    </div>
```

what do you think about it. What can be wrong here?